# display any value from django views to html form input

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I'm working on Django app and i have only one page in my templates directory named "index", everything is working well but i faced a problem when i wanted to display the result which will be passed by Django views to my HTML page. I want the value to be displayed on my input field instead of printing it on the browser. I searched a lot but i couldn't found anything related to this.

I have three fields:

1. key field.
2. Plaintext field.
3. Ciphertext field.
   and one button for encryption & decryption.

I need when i click on the button, the result will be displayed on my Ciphertext field not on the browser because i already did that before.

Can you help me?

Thanks..

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the multiple ways is to,

- render the template from view.
- pass the values for "key field" and "plain text filed" into the context variable (ex: **return render(request, context={'key_filed': key_field_value, 'plain_text_field': plain_text_field_value}** ).
- Use these values in "value=" field of < input > tag. (ex: **< inpu type='text' value={{ key_filed }} > and < inpu type='text' value={{ plain_text_field }} >**)

Comment: Thanks. You need to add a double quotation between the rendering value because in your case will not working, so you need to do it in this way:                     <input type="text" name="myciphertxt" placeholder="...." value="{{cipher_value}}"